# Changing Windows 10 snap assist (back to the way Win8/7 had it)

Tags: windows-10, aero-snap, windows-snap-assist

> Note: For the sake of saving myself some typing, I'm omitting the <kbd>Windows</kbd> from my key combinations.

So I'm used to being able to hit <kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd> to snap my windows around the screen, moving (when using the right arrow) from the right side of the scren to the left side and back. Windows 10 has a similar feature, with some nice qualities -- when you snap two windows, you can resize both at the same time, for example, and you can fill vertical space automatically instead of having to resize manually.

However, I have to very, very large problems with it: Its behavior is inconsistent, and sometimes it just flat-out doesn't work the way it's supposed to. I could give examples of each, but this isn't a bug report.

Anyway, since I doubt these bugs will be fixed for a while, in the mean time I'd like to return to the old Windows 7 way of doing things. How can I?

Alternatively, are there any third-party programs which can give me the same functionality, but functional? I'm mostly interested in <kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd> to snap the windows to the sides, <kbd>↑</kbd> to maximize the window, and <kbd>↓</kbd> to minimize it (or go from maximized to what it was just before). However, working integration of the Windows 10 features, like multiple window resizing, filling in extra space, not just half the screen, etc. would also be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap) is an alternative to Aero Snap and has a lot more functions. You can also customize the way it behaviors (Example: Moving a window to the top would snap it to the right). I haven't tested in it Windows 10, but you can give it a try.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a Windows setting of some sort, but if there isn't, I'll use AquaSnap and accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to just disable the special resize function, go to Settings -> System -> Multitasking and turn off "Automatically adjust the size of all adjacent windows when I resize one". It might not exactly be this, since I run Windows 10 in French.